# How can I handle a button event that triggers user control creation?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have an ASP.NET web form on which I'm displaying a list of database items via user controls, generating the user controls dynamically - working fine.

Also on the page, I have an asp:dropdownlist filled with items that can be added to this database list.  Along with this dropdown I have a button 'ADD'.  My intent is that the user chooses and item, clicks add, and then the list of user controls on the form will include this new item.

I have all this working.

My issue is that the user control has a button 'DELETE', which removes the selected item from the list.  That works, EXCEPT when I add a new item.  Because my 'add' button event is always fired after Page_Load, even if I regenerate the list of user controls, the internal user control click events won't fire because the controls weren't created as part of Page_Load.

I need to know what I'm doing wrong, or best practices here, any advice.  I tried to be precise in the description of the problem, but if I've not succeeded, let me know and I can add more details.

SIMPLE RESTATE: I need to know how to add a dynamically created user control to a page via a page button click event, and still have the user control internal click(etc) events firing.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Based on the feedback from the gentlemen here, and doing some further research related to their suggestions, I ended up implementing a solution based on what's presented on this page:

http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx

Here's a snippet showing how I dealt with this.  This snippet resides in my PreInit event handler.  Not exactly an elegant weapon for a civilized age, but sometimes a blaster is all you've got to use.

```
'Look to see if button for adding a new client number has been
'clicked.  If so, call the sub to add the item NOW, so that it
'is able to have it's internal click events fire.
For Each control_string As String In Request.Form
  Dim ctl As Control = Page.FindControl(control_string)

  If (ctl IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ctl.ID = "cmdAddClientNumber") Then
    Me.AddClientNumberToList()
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense...why would you want the added control to  "have it's internal click events fire" when it's first added? The normal flow of something like this is: Step 1: User clicks "cmdAddClientNumber"; Step 2: In cmdAddClientNumber_Click, you AddClientNumberToList; Step 3: User clicks some button in "ClientNumber"; Step 4: In PreInit, you call AddClientNumberToList; Step 5: ASP.NET takes care of calling "ClientNumber.SomeButton_Click" in response to the user action.
If you need any more details than that - you're going to have show more code.

Comment: Makes perfect sense with all due respect, and solved my issue.  I create a user control via a button click event.  That control has its own delete button to allow the user to remove it from the list.  If an item gets added by accident the user needs to be able to click the delete button on that user control to remove it.   My issue is solved.   If that isn't clear enough, dumping all my code to this page won't help.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button handler, you initially add the UserControl to the Page. OnPreInit (which will next be fired when the user clicks Delete on the UserControl), you should *re-add* the UserControl - so that it exists, and can handle the Delete button event.

You will need to devise your own state tracking mechanism to determine that you need to add the UserControl during PreInit. I generally use ViewState, as evidenced by [this seemingly similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099397/viewstate-and-controls-in-asp-net/9100148#9100148).

Comment: Mark, thanks sir - you and Rick I think have confirmed my worries concerning this.  To be clear, I have my dynamic controls recreated, and the internal click events working just fine, except for when adding one via a button click event.  When going down this path, I wondered if user controls were worth the effort, instead of just using good old fashioned request.item and tracking things myself.  I was trying to stay all in .NET event land.  Guess that's not gonna work...which is aggravating.

Comment: Show your event hookups for your dynamic controls, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question:
[How to create and use custom control with UpdatePanel added to the page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241856/how-to-create-and-use-custom-control-with-updatepanel-added-to-the-page-programm)

Dynamic control should be re-added to the control tree `OnPreInit`, see documentation:

**PreInit** - Create or re-create dynamic controls.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I can certainly do that, but how does that address the problem I've described here?

Comment: Do your add as you have it, just the re-creation has to happen earlier so in the next postback, your new controls gets added in time for ASP.NET to wire it back up and fire the events you are looking for. Dynamic controls and eventing can be very confusing.

Comment: I'll add the creation of them in PreInit - thanks for that advice.
 However I don't think that addresses the problem I've described.  My issue is that if I click my 'add' button, that event fires after all Init/Load events.  I can regenerate the dynamic controls at that point so that the user can SEE the new item in the list, but the internal user control click events won't fire.  That's my problem - hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Can you show the code on how you wire up the dynamic controls click events?

Comment: Rick, I'm not sure exactly what you're wanting to see.  Do you have a suspicion of something?  I'm guessing that if the only way a user control click event can be caught is if the control is added in Init/Load, then I'm going to have to do what Mark suggests and track things myself, instead of using .NET events.  It what it is I suppose.